# Predefine callback parameters within class

Tags: node.js

I have a `Command` class defined like so

```
class Command {

  constructor(name, permission, callback)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.permission = permission;
    this.callback = callback;
  }
}

module.exports.command = Command;
```

Is there a way I can predefine the structure of `callback`, so it needs the exact same parameters every time, so you can only define it one way?

For example, if I wanted the callback function to always have the arguments `client` and `args` then the constructor would only accept a callback with the arguments `client` and `args`

Comment: *Is there a way I can predefine the structure of callback such that it requires those exact parameters every time?* - I'm not sure what exactly this means. Can you clarify?

Comment: @estus I've edited it, hope that clears it up

Comment: What is *define it one way*? Please, describe how you expect the class and the callback to behave.

Comment: @estus edited it with an example, should be good now :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to assert function arity:

```
if (callback.length !== 2)
  throw new Error('Callback should have 2 parameters');
```

It's acceptable to rely on function arity in some cases. But this is potential antipattern that may be harmful in different ways, especially since ES6.

Default values or rest operator can make a function appear as parameterless, while it isn't:

```
(function (foo = 1) {}).length === 0;

(function (...args) {}).length === 0;
```

Comment: So in theory I should just assume that the class is going to be used responsibly and just hope for the best

Comment: Yes. A proper documentation (JSDoc) is enough. You can use typed JS (TypeScript or Flow) if you want to address such potential problems at build time.